# How to implement onback press in fragment in Android Studio

Tags: android

I want that whenever the user presses back in any fragment, user will moved into main activity.

MainActivity.java

```html
package com.thechamp.ait;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case    R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AboutCollege()).commit();
                break;

            case    R.id.nav_Earnmoney:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new EarnMoney()).commit();
                break;

            case    R.id.nav_Feedback:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Feedback()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_notice:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new NoticeBoard()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_study:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new StudyMaterial()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_support:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Support()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}}
```

and here Feedback Fragment code -
I want that whenever user press back button then user moved to main activity.

```html
package com.thechamp.ait;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Feedback extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feedback, container, false);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();





           return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, religious incantations and exhortations, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
          if(shouldInterceptBackPress()){
            // your logic when backpress is clicked
          }else{
            isEnabled = false
            main.activity?.onBackPressed()
          }
        }
    })
}
```

[Check From Android Documantation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back)